# How to update a table in oracle based on another table field?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my query

```
SELECT * FROM ELP_CERT, ELP_CERT_PAYMENT WHERE ELP_CERT.CERT_NUMBER='00190005622'and
ELP_CERT.CERT_ID = ELP_CERT_PAYMENT.CERT_ID
```

This is for select and there is a field common by name `DATE_PAID_FOR`. So, Based on the above condition how can i update `ELP_CERT_PAYMENT.date_PAID_FOR` in oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this:

```
update (
  select *
    from elp_cert, elp_cert_payment 
   where elp_cert.cert_number='00190005622'
     and elp_cert.cert_id = elp_cert_payment.cert_id
)
set date_paid_for = ...
```

It works if there is a foreign key in `elp_cert_payment` referencing `elp_cert`.

Comment: Hi Tony It is showing Invalid Identifier Date_paid_for

Comment: Sorry, removed unwanted alias now.

Comment: Hi Tony I am not using any Aliases

Comment: Just copy and paste my code from above, I have changed it since you first tried it.  It used to have an alias in it `set elp_cert_payment.date_paid_for`, now it does not.

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a simplier solution, but this update should work

```
update ELP_CERT_PAYMENT ecp set date_PAID_FOR = (
    select ec.date_PAID_FOR from ELP_CERT ec where ec.cert_id = ecp.cert_id
) where date_PAID_FOR in (
    select ec.date_PAID_FOR from ELP_CERT ec where ec.cert_id = ecp.cert_id 
        and ec.CERT_NUMBER='00190005622'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MERGE INTO ELP_CERT_PAYMENT A
USING ELP_CERT B
ON (A.CERT_ID=B.CERT_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET A.date_PAID_FOR=B.date_PAID_FOR
WHERE
 A.CERT_NUMBER='00190005622';

Here, we are updating ELP_CERT_PAYMENT table
using ELP_CERT table.